# Hastag format regex for (#word or word)

Tags: regex

I have problem with regular expressions

```
/\A[#a-z]+[#a-z0-9\-\s_.']*\z/
```

I would like to match result like

> aaa #aaa

Words with hashtag or words without hashtag. But my regex allow to create

> a#a

How can I change that?

Comment: Try [`/\A[#a-z][a-z0-9_.'-]*(?:\s+[#a-z][a-z0-9_.'-]*)*\z`](http://rubular.com/r/xCHT2l7a2B).

Comment: @EdKarpacki Is `aaa #aaa #` a valid input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match words optionally starting with `#`:

```
(?>\B#|(?<=\s|^))[a-zA-Z][\w'.-]*(?=\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ3zV1/4)

Comment: it is very good and works - but I still have problem: #aaa aaa a#a - should match 2 words (#aaa aaa) - but this regex didn't allow for that

Comment: OK try my updated answer now. I am on mobile so unable to fix the demo link

Comment: It is better but if # is on the middle of word for example a#aaa - this regex accept aaa - and this is wrong :) and I would like to create one character word for example result: **a** is correct, but in this regex don't.

Comment: It is work but now I have problem with disallowed signs for example: aa^aa - match aa aa - but whole word with disallowed signs shouldn't be matched.

Answer (score 2):

From the question and your comments, it is unclear, what a word boundary should be. You might want something similar to this:

```
(?<=^|\s|["'])#?[a-zA-Z]+\b(?=$|\s|[,;.:?!"'])
```

**Assumptions:**

- Words consist only of letters.
- Words are delimited by spaces or special characters at beginning (`"'`) and end (`,;.:?!"'`).

The rationale for the special characters is:

- `for example: food` also yields `example`
- `set to "on"` also yields `on`

You may wish to extend those lists of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
#?[^# \n]+
```

You can learn how to build and test your regular expressions [on this website](http://regexr.com/).

Usage example in Java (added ^ and $ to the pattern to indicate start/end of the string):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testFor("aaa");
    testFor("#aaa");
    testFor("a#a");
}

public static void testFor(String toTest) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^#?[^# \\n]+$");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(toTest);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Ouput

```
aaa
#aaa
```

Comment: What programming language / library / function are you using to check if string matches the pattern? I edited my answer and added example in Java.

Comment: I use ruby, but for regex I used this [page](http://rubular.com/) - this regex is for validation. It should return only words with (_.') - and optional words with # ( #aaa) - only first sign should be a hash.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/FVxtxIXxKw - I'm not sure what you have trouble with. Could you please add some more examples that should / shouldn't match?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!\w)#\w+|(?<!#)\w+(?!#)
```

Should do the trick if your regex engine supports lookahead and lookbehind.